# In Python, how do I extract multiple blocks of text that begin with same pattern, but no distinct end?

Tags: python, regex, findall

Given a test string:

```
teststr= 'chapter 1 Here is a block of text from chapter one.  chapter 2 Here is another block of text from the second chapter.  chapter 3 Here is the third and final block of text.'
```

I want to create a list of results like this:

```
result=['chapter 1 Here is a block of text from chapter one.','chapter 2 Here is another block of text from the second chapter.','chapter 3 Here is the third and final block of text.']
```

Using `re.findall('chapter [0-9]',teststr)`

I get `['chapter 1', 'chapter 2', 'chapter 3']`

That's fine if all I wanted were the chapter numbers, but I want the chapter number plus all the text up to the next chapter number.  In the case of the last chapter, I want to get the chapter number and the text all the way to the end.

Trying `re.findall('chapter [0-9].*',teststr)` yields the greedy result:
`['chapter 1 Here is a block of text from chapter one.  chapter 2 Here is another block of text from the second chapter.  chapter 3 Here is the third and final block of text.']`

I'm not great with regular expressions so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `pattern = re.compile(r'chapter (?:(?!\s+chapter \d+).)+')` and use `pattern.findall`

Comment: You could improve your example by adding some text at the beginning that did not include "chapter". To identify a match must "chapter be followed by one space, one or more digits then at least one space? Can "chapter" be "Chapter"? These question arise from the fact that you are asking a question in terms of a single example. That rarely makes the question unabiguous. You need to state your question in words, precisely and unambiguously, then use one or more examples for illustration...

Comment: ..Here's an example of a possible statement of the question that is intended to be complete and unambiguous (but is only my guess of what you want): "I wish to extract all strings that begin '[cC]hapter d+ ', where '[cC]' represents a 'c' or a 'C' and 'd+' represents one or more digits, and ends with a period, followed by zero or more spaces followed by the end of the string or another string '[cC]hapter d+ '".

Comment: To make case insensitive, `pattern = re.compile(r'(?i)chapter (?:(?!\s+chapter \d+).)+')` and then use `matches = pattern.findall(teststr)`

Comment: @ChrisCharley, that works great!  I appreciate you getting me on track, but any chance you can help me understand how that works?  Some of these regex expressions seem cryptic to me so I would greatly appreciate a breakdown of what's happening.

Comment: `(?I)` makes case insensitive, so it would match `Chapter or CHAPTER or chapter` `(?:  … ` is a non capturing group with a single dot (matches anything) matched 1 or more times up until `(?!\s+chapter \d+)` matches (the next possible chapter or end of string).

Comment: @ChrisCharley, how do I mark your answer as the accepted answer since you answered in the comments?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I really appreciate your suggestion.  However, I asked the question as I intended, specifying the inputs and outputs and what I tried.  It seems to have all worked out really well and must have been clear enough.  Yes, I did have a specific test example that applies generally to similar patterns, so I don't think it is ambiguous at all.  ChrisCharley provided a great answer that can be broadly applied to similar patterns.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe `re.split(r'(?!^)(?=chapter \d)', teststr)` is enough? See [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/AEW6vn).

Comment: A change to recognize digits following chapter. `pattern = re.compile(r'chapter \d+(?:(?!\s+chapter \d+).)+')`

Comment: @ChrisCharley do you want to put your answer in answer form so we can mark it as answered?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, an extraction regex looks like

```
(?s)pattern.*?(?=pattern|$)
```

Or, if the `pattern` is at the start of a line,

```
(?sm)^pattern.*?(?=\npattern|\Z)
```

Here, you could use

```py
re.findall(r'chapter [0-9].*?(?=chapter [0-9]|\Z)', text)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQvq7A/1). *Details*:

- `chapter [0-9]` - `chapter` + space and a digit
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?=chapter [0-9]|\Z)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with `chapter`, space, digit, or end of the whole string.

Here, since the text starts with the keyword, you may use

```
import re
teststr= 'chapter 1 Here is a block of text from chapter one.  chapter 2 Here is another block of text from the second chapter.  chapter 3 Here is the third and final block of text.'
my_result = [x.strip() for x in re.split(r'(?!^)(?=chapter \d)', teststr)]
print( my_result )
# => ['chapter 1 Here is a block of text from chapter one.', 'chapter 2 Here is another block of text from the second chapter.', 'chapter 3 Here is the third and final block of text.']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sr6qis). The `(?!^)(?=chapter \d)` regex means:

- `(?!^)` - find a location that is not at the start of string and
- `(?=chapter \d)` - is immediately followed with `chapter`, space and any digit.

The pattern is used to split the string at the found locations, and does not consume any chars, hence, the results are stripped from whitespace in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `re.split`. Assuming up to 99 chapters:

```
import re
teststr= 'chapter 1 Here is a block of text from chapter one.  chapter 2 Here is another block of text from the second chapter.  chapter 3 Here is the third and final block of text.'

chapters = [i.strip() for i in re.split('chapter \d{1,2}', teststr)[1:]]
```

#### Output:

```
['Here is a block of text from chapter one.',
 'Here is another block of text from the second chapter.',
 'Here is the third and final block of text.']
```

Comment: Now it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use a regex, try this:

```
def split(text):
    chapters = []

    this_chapter = ""
    for i, c in enumerate(text):
        if text[i:].startswith("chapter ") and text[i+8].isdigit():
            if this_chapter.strip():
                chapters.append(this_chapter.strip())
            this_chapter = c
        else:
            this_chapter += c

    chapters.append(this_chapter.strip())

    return chapters

print(split('chapter 1 Here is a block of text from chapter one.  chapter 2 Here is another block of text from the second chapter.  chapter 3 Here is the third and final block of text.'))
```

Output:

```
['chapter 1 Here is a block of text from chapter one.', 'chapter 2 Here is another block of text from the second chapter.', 'chapter 3 Here is the third and final block of text.']
```